# Переход по ссылке на динамическую страницу

Tags: php

Есть форма и обработчик формы. 
На обработчик могу перейти по кнопке. 
Необходимо также на этот же обработчик попасть по ссылке. 
Если использовать метод GET , то тут понятно. просто передать на эту страницу в адресной строке параметр. 
Можно ли осуществить это с помощью POST?
Не очень доверяю GET, так как злоумышленник может передать любые параметры , и вид url портится.

Comment: передавайте через скрытое поле

Comment: а в POST злоумышленник не может передать любые параметры ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По первому вопросу:

```
<form action="/formhandler/" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="123" name="input1"> 
<input type="hidden" value="456" name="input2"> 
</form> 
<a href="#" onclick="{document.forms[0].submit();return false;}">ай! ой!</a>
```

По второму - это ни разу не поможет, потому что через POST любые данные передаются любым злым дядькой так же легко, как и через GET.